# Integer Map Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, map, dictionary, lookup

For my project, I need to map integers so that inputting `int X` will output `int Y` where both `X` and `Y` are defined during runtime.

I've used `Dictionary<int,int>` in .NET but its memory use is too high and the access speed is too long for my case.

Instead, I want to make a custom class that essentially does what a `Dictionary<int,int>` does in that it maps an integer key to an integer value.

What is the underlying concept behind the Dictionary and how would I implement something like it?

Note: I don't need to remove elements or check if the collection contains an element. I only need to be able to define input-output pairs and access the outputs with inputs.

Comment: So, you want to code a Dictionary, that isn't a Dictionary, but behaves like a Dictionary, without the memory use of a Dictionary that is somehow faster than O(1)... but isn't a Dictionary. Did I get that right?

Comment: No, I want to code something that accomplishes one of the things a Dictionary accomplishes.

Comment: The thing you are asking for is a Dictionary. Remove, check, and contains are just bits you get on the side that come with the underlying data structure. `ContainsKey` is a trivial tweak to `TryGetValue`. Look at the [reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) and see if you can make it faster or take less memory (I assure you that if you are able to do one, you will pay a heavy price for it in the other).

Comment: Maybe you can use Binary Search Tree. It will use way less memory but it will be slower to access values (but can be faster to access sequential data). BTW which language are you using? Maybe you can use a compiled language instead of scripting language.

Comment: @MichaelIT I'd rather not prune through the 1148 lines of code in the Dictionary's source code. In any case, it'll be fun and edifying to make my own map.

Comment: @Mandril I'm interested in the idea of using a binary search tree but I'm not sure how it would work for mapping. I.e. How would 123456 paired to 7 output 7?

Comment: @JPtheK9 A binary search tree consists of nodes, linked together to form a binary tree. After you inserted a `(123456, 7)` into the tree, there will be a node *somewhere* that will have the key 123456 and value 7. When a search is performed, this node will be *somehow* reached, when implemented correctly. If you had to ask this question, I suspect that you will need to pick up a "Data Structures and Algorithms" textbook before asking any questions further. (flagging this question for speedy deletion.)

Comment: The underlying concept behind a dictionary is a Hashtable or Binary Tree.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source code of the dictionary and noticed the use of "buckets". I'm not exactly sure how a dictionary sorts objects into buckets but it's a simple task with integers.

The main problem, I've logiced, is converting the input into an index that's small as possible yet doesn't collide with other inputs' indexes to make the array the outputs are stored in as small as possible, which is where buckets come in.

If the input is 255, the array can't be that large to store the output in the index of 255. Instead, operations are done on the number to determine where its output is stored.

Here's my implementation. It's optimized for my particular use because the largest key is 255.

```
public class FastMap {
    //8 buckets because the maximum key is 255
    public int[][] Buckets = new int[][8];

    public void Add (int input, int output)
    {
        //Finding out which bucket output will be assigned in
        int bucketIndex = input % 32;
        //Finding out the index inside of the bucket the output will be assigned to
        int innerIndex = input / 32;
        //Dropping output into the necessary bucket
        int[] bucket = Buckets[bucketIndex];
        if (bucket == null) 
        {
            bucket = new int[8];
            Buckets[bucketIndex] = bucket;
        }
        bucket[innerIndex] = output;
    }
    public int GetValue (int input)
    {
        return (Buckets[input % 32][input / 32]);
    }
}
```

I'm going to be playing with this more but already, my implementation out-performs `Dictionary<int,int>` in both memory use and performance.

Comment: The reason your question was unanswerable was because you failed to mention the 255 constraint.

Comment: [Chain bucket hash collision resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining).

Comment: How the hell is a Dictionary's memory usage too high if you only have 255 int,int pairs? That is using somewhere around 2**K**.

Comment: I would suggest that once you get the code working, that you post this class on CodeReview.SE to get feedback on it (also to see if there's a better way to do it that might have slipped one's mind).

Comment: @Telastyn I have about 2000 of those dictionaries.

Comment: @JPtheK9 - oh no! 4 meg! That is breaking the bank!

Comment: Why are you being so condescending? I know more about my project than you do and I stated that a dictionary would not work. In any case, my problem is solved so your comment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is merely provided to reduce the frustration. In general, a person is better advised to learn how to conduct performance benchmarking ***properly*** before asking such a question.

If your "keys" exclusively consist of consecutive integers, you can use an integer array. Zero-based consecutive integers can be used as array index as-is. Non-zero-based consecutive integers may require an index value adjustment before using it with an array.

Even if the keys are not strictly consecutive, in that there are a small amount of holes (unused integer values between the minimum and maximum keys), it might still be beneficial performance-wise to use an array.

Remember that using an array makes your code fragile (more easily broken) to changes. Therefore, carefully analyze your project's current and future needs, and document the limitations inside your code comments, or somehow make them obvious to your project's users.

If there is some magic mathematical functions that map your integer keys into your lookup values, test to see whether that will be faster.

If your dictionary is constructed incrementally (adding keys one by one), consider using the `Dictionary` constructor with the size preallocation option,  with an estimate of the maximum size needed. This reduces the time spent in reallocating and rehashing.

As pointed out in others' comments, you can benchmark with [`SortedDictionary` (docs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx), which is typically, but not guaranteed to be a binary search tree.

If you know that the distribution of your integer keys may have unusual statistical distribution characteristics (for example, all of your keys are even-numbered, and so on), you may have to implement a workaround:

- Depending on the `Dictionary` implementation, a workaround might not be necessary if it is already implemented from within.
- Otherwise, you will need to apply a "key diffusion / avalanche function" to your integer keys, and use the modified key as a hash table index inside a typical "modulo-N" hash table.

  - A typical good choice (for hash tables) is the MurmurHash3 function.

A sorted int-int dictionary that is initialized up-front and never changed can be re-implemented as an array of integer pairs, and lookup can be performed with binary search.

If the int-int mapping comes from some mathematical functions that has monotonic trends, it might be possible to perform the table lookup faster than binary search.